# Extract Image and embed it in img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

For a project im working on, i would like to embed instagram profile pictures.
I have to url to the image but im unable to embed it into my html page.
Please take a look at this example:
https://scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/281440578_1088265838702675_6233856337905829714_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=h-rdLy5hFZwAX9TGYME&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT_w7YGvusOUvMZr3vi2OQytijTeogbw-J74X1jSyzq9pw&oe=62A11F98&_nc_sid=498da5

This link shows the profile picture from instagram. I cannot use this link directly as a src for an img tag. When taking a look at the source code on this link the img tag there uses the same link. How can i extract the image and embed it to a html page?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images or other sites here.

Comment: _"I have to url to the image"_ - and where exactly did you get that from?

Comment: @isherwood i am not asking to debug any site. I am asking how to extract images when they have the format seen above. I not only encountered this problem on instagram.

Comment: @CBroe Its the url provided above. I extracted the link from instagram.

Comment: That URL responds with `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin` - meaning, browsers are explicitly forbidden from displaying this resource on other sites. You will probably have to use the API to get an image URL that they _allow_ you to display somewhere else

Comment: @isherwood i did. Maybe the title is not specific enough, but I described the problem and provided additional information (link). I could add that i also tried to use the iframe tag and that this also did not do the trick.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see what error you are getting. I ran simply this code <img src="the url you gave"> and saw the same error as @CBroe reported. Make sure also that if you are tempted to copy the image into your own space that instagram allows that in its terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler for you to download that image,place it   in the same folder and use it ,it does not waste a lot of memory

Also welcome to Stack Overflow ,I am new here too

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="https://scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19`   /281440578_1088265838702675_6233856337905829714_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=h-rdLy5hFZwAX9TGYME&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT_w7YGvusOUvMZr3vi2OQytijTeogbw-J74X1jSyzq9pw&oe=62A11F98&_nc_sid=498da5">

</body>
```

But if you have to do this ,do it

Comment: Are you certain that the terms of service allow you to do this?

Comment: You can give them credits below the image.

Comment: @UserThatProgram'sHorribly Downloading is not really an option. I want to have it change dynamically. The instagram profile picture is just an example